# Magento Catalosearch not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I have Magento1.9 store and have above 30000 products, all products was coming on frontend when searching by keyword, but suddenly for some specific keyword catalog search return "No products matching selection", I reindexed all indexes but still products are not showing on search page.

When I save any product from admin panel (for matching keyword) then it started to come in search result. But when I save product (for matching keyword) from frontend using product object like

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(13500)->save()
```

then that product should be display on search page, but this is not happening.

I didn't get what's wrong with the magento products.

Please suggest.

Comment: did you add your code as $product->setVisibility(4) while saving?

Comment: Yes, and it is showing "catalog, search" in admin grid. and product page also working properly.

Answer (score 0):

There're quite an array of reasons why this may be happening. A very good place to start, which covers the usual pitfalls, would be ASchroder's article:

[Why are my Magento products not showing up?!](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/)

1. Ensure that the product(s) you expect to show in the results have: Status = Enabled & Visibility: Search or Catalogue, Search
2. Reindex your store,
3. Refresh all caches

Ensure that if your store has limitations for inventory (i.e hide out of stock products), that the product(s) are in-stock.

Comment: Hello @Moose, all are done in magento store, my product single page is working and showing in home page also only all products are not coming in catalogsearch page, when I save from admin then the product start to come in search result.

Comment: If calling `->save();` on the product results in it returning to the search index, it would seem like your search index is corrupted. Were these products run via import? Otherwise, start looking through your logs as well.